# How to pass arguments to TCPServer handler class

Tags: python, socketserver

Here's a piece of experimental/educational code written solely to "play" with *socketserver* functionality.

The code works without error. All it does is open and read a file sending the file's contents over a TCP connection to a TCPServer. The server prints the received data during the overridden *handle()* function of *BaseRequestHandler*.

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM
from socketserver import BaseRequestHandler, TCPServer
from threading import Thread

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 10101
ADDR = HOST, PORT
RECVBUF = 4096
SENDBUF = RECVBUF // 2
INPFILE = "inputfile.txt"


class MyHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        while data := self.request.recv(RECVBUF):
            print(data.decode(), end="")


def server(tcpserver: TCPServer):
    tcpserver.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open(INPFILE, "rb") as indata:
        with TCPServer(ADDR, MyHandler) as tcpserver:
            (t := Thread(target=server, args=[tcpserver])).start()
            with socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) as s:
                s.connect(ADDR)
                while chunk := indata.read(SENDBUF):
                    s.sendall(chunk)
            tcpserver.shutdown()
            t.join()
```

So this is fine but what if I want the *handle()* function to write the received data to a file? Sure, I could hard-code the filename into the *handle()* function or maybe even make it globally available. Neither of those options seem particularly Pythonic to me.

The TCPServer is constructed based on a RequestHandler type - i.e., not a class instance. What I really want to be able to do is (somehow) pass a filename into the MyHandler class. The TCPServer instance will (presumably) have an internal instance variable for the constructed MyHandler but that's not documented so I don't know where that is.

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental but I just can't figure out the "right" way to do achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of getting around this API limitation is to use class factory function:

```
def get_handler(fname):
    class MyHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
            while data := self.request.recv(RECVBUF):
                print(data.decode(), end="")
                # copy it to file, I dunno =)
                with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(data)
    return MyHandler
```

Then use it like that:

```
    with TCPServer(ADDR, get_handler('/tmp/file.bin')) as tcpserver:
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option would be to take a look into internal [***socket*** module API](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/socketserver.py) and subclass `TCPServer` to override `finish_request()` method:

```
class MyTCPServer(TCPServer):
    finish_request(self, request, client_address):
        """ That's the only method where handler is used:
            could be easily overridden
        """
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
```

There's a lot of ways to go from here:

- introduce something like `MyTCPServer.filename` attribute and pass it as another constructor argument to `RequestHandlerClass`
- replace handler class instatiation with function call or callable class instance call
- maybe override `__init__()` to essentially rename `self.RequestHandlerClass` to be more explicit if it's not treated like a class anymore

Overall, `BaseRequestHandler` API is quite simple and easy to extend.